# Show 2 count in 1 result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to display a single result so that I can extract it.

This is my table named 'TRY'

```
id | type |
01 |  A   |
01 |  D   |
01 |  A   |
```

My query is like this:

```
select 
    lpad(id,2,'0')||
    lpad(count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end),3,'0')||
    lpad(count(case when type = 'D' then 1 end),3,'0')||
    lpad(count(case when type in ('A','D') then 1 end),3,'0') then 1 end)
    as results 
from 
    TRY 
group by 
    id
    ,type
```

I want the result to show like this `01002001003` but instead I got 2 result which are like this 
`01002000002` and `01000001001`. I just want to combine the count result as one.

Comment: Are you sure this your query? This query will give you syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main thing that you need to consider is how the [`GROUP BY` clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php) actually works, as you have actually grouped by `id` and `type` meaning that you'll never have a positive count for type A and type D on the same row as they are not grouped together.

In your example I have noticed the following and worked to these parameters:

- You want to `GROUP BY id` (not `GROUP BY id, type`)
- Your returned result is a concatenated string which consists of

  - the id (padded to 2 characters)
  - the number of Type A's (padded to 3 characters)
  - the number of type D (padded to 3 characters)
  - the total number of A's and D's combined. (padded to 3 characters)

You actually also want to be using the [`SUM` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/sum.php) instead of [`COUNT`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/count.php) so something along the lines of the following should work:

**Oracle/PLSQL**

```
SELECT
    LPAD(id,2,'0')
    || LPAD(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),3,'0')
    || LPAD(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),3,'0')
    || LPAD(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' OR type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),3,'0')
    AS results
FROM
    TRY
GROUP BY
    id
```

On the unlikely off-chance you're actually using SQL Server or another Database engine the `LPAD` function will not actually work so using something along the lines of the following may work instead. (Also added in case some non ORACLE users have a similar quandary and it's what I used to resolve your issue)

```
SELECT
    [results] = 
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[id]),2)
        + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),3)
        + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),3)
        + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 'A' OR type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),3)
FROM
    [TRY]
GROUP BY
    [id]
```